# ASP.NET MVC Multi Project Areas Questions with setup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

For those who setup muli project areas in ASP.NET MVC 2 in VS 2010, I have a few questions for you:

- Can other project areas use one master page?  Or does each have to have their own master page?
- What about the web.config file?  Does each area need the config file?  Or does it rely on the master?
- I tried removing the master page reference, but I get an intellisense error and  failed to monitor changes after following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx

I assume I need to leave in the master page so that at least works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can other project areas use one master
>   page?

Yes.  The master page is just a file, and it can be referenced anywhere in your application

> What about the web.config file?

There is a web.config in each area. In my application they all look exactly the same, so I assume the application is taking its settings from each individual web.config, and that the root area also has its own individual settings in the root web.config.

Comment: 1) OK, how do you make the reference being that the area projects are at the same level, do you do ../MasterProject/Site/Shared/site.master or something like that?  What reference do you specify?  2) OK, I assume it will ignore the master config, but I'll leave it there and modify the parent project config only.  Thanks.

Comment: If the master page is being shared by more than one area, it should reside at the root of the application (in its usual place).

Comment: Ah, I see, there is a web.config in each area.  In my application they all look exactly the same, so I assume the application is taking its settings from each individual web.config, and that the root area also has its own individual settings.

Comment: This sounds more like a single-project, but multi-area answer. How does one reference a master page in a separate project (but within the same site)?